# How to find cumulative density function

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve the problem below using CDF and kinda lost. Can someone show me how it is done?

What is the probability that I roll two dice and they add up to at most 9?

$F(x) = P(X <= x)$

$F(9) = P(X <= 9)$

Do I make some table or something? I'm really lost.

Comment: [How many faces does the die have](https://paulsperambulations.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/d4_4_sided_pyramid_dice_5_black-500x500-e1399242540877.jpg)?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X,Y$ denote the first and the 2nd rolls and let $S=X+Y$. Note that
$$
\mathbb{P}[S \le 9] = 1 - \mathbb{P}[S=12] - \mathbb{P}[S=11] - \mathbb{P}[S=10]
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes this is clear. One question tho, Would P(S = 12) = 1/3 ? `P(X = 6) = 1/6 and P(Y = 6) = 1/6. 1/6 + 1/6 = 1/3`